# Split a single array with respect to comma in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting an array of single string `$scope.Obj= ["Talking Spanish,Spanish food,Spanish things,Football"];`

The split should be by watching `,`

I need to break it down = `["Talking Spanish","Spanish food","Spanish things","Football"];`

How can I do it  using javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
let arr = ["Talking Spanish,Spanish food,Spanish things,Football"];

let op = arr[0].split(',')

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split 0th index of $scope.Obj with , and reassign to $scope.Obj.

```js
$scope={};
$scope.Obj= ["Talking Spanish,Spanish food,Spanish things,Football"];
$scope.Obj=$scope.Obj[0].split(",")
console.log($scope.Obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

str.split(separator, limit)
The above is common syntax to split a array
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580

Answer (score 0):

The `split()` method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings, using a specified separator string to determine where to make each split.

In the following example, `split()` looks for spaces in a string and returns the first 3 splits that it finds.

```
var myString = 'Hello World. How are you doing?';
var splits = myString.split(' ', 3);

console.log(splits);
```

This script displays the following:

```
["Hello", "World.", "How"]
```